# How to register a click event on something that only accepts tap events

Tags: javascript, touch-event, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to load a mobile-specific website in to an iFrame that is meant to be viewed on a desktop browser. Unfortunately some of the events on the mobile-specific website only register taps, and not clicks, and therefor the site is pretty useless within the iframe.

Fortunately I am able to stick a JS script in to the header of the mobile specific site, so I was wondering if there was any way that I can fire a click event on the target that is meant to be tapped on.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @AlienArrays unfortunately I can't alter the actual mobile site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
    event.target.touch();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `.touch()` is supposed to invoke, is this a plugin function?

Comment: Aha! Because the site already uses jQuery, I used a combination of your answer and the resulting action: `$(this).trigger('touchend');`. BOOM!